# How to use Stackdriver with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stackdriver

I am working on a flutter app. Is there any method available to write data directly from Flutter/Dart to StackDriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis

Example:

```
import 'package:googleapis/logging/v2.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

final _credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
{
... YOUR CREDENTIALS ....
}
''');

const _SCOPES = const ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write'];

clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _SCOPES).then((httpClient) {
  var errorReporting = new LoggingApi(httpClient);

  // Resource
  var resource = new MonitoredResource();
  resource.type = 'global';
  resource.labels = {
    'project_id': 'PROJECT_ID',
  };

  // Prepare new log entry.
  LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
  logEntry.logName = "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/LOG_ID";
  logEntry.jsonPayload = {'message': 'YOUR MESSAGE'};
  logEntry.resource = resource;

  var request = new WriteLogEntriesRequest();
  request.entries = [logEntry];

  errorReporting.entries.write(request).then((_) {
    print('log entry sent');
  });
});
```

But, BE AWARE, you will need to put your credentials on your flutter app and "hackers" can steal it. So, probably is better to send your logs to backend and then send this to StackDriver.

Comment: Have you tried this? I can't use `googleapis_auth` due to its dependency on `dart:html`

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to show how is possible to do using dart/flutter. But the right way should be creating a "log backend" and from there, send stuff to StackDriver.

Answer (score 1):

In order to write logs to Stackdriver, you must be authenticated with the Google Cloud Platform. Generally speaking, you have 2 options for authentication:

#### 1. Username-password

Sign in using `google_sign_in`, which creates a client that you can use with `googleapis` and later on utilize the different APIs available.

#### 2. Service account

Read a generated credentials JSON file and use `clientViaServiceAccount`. This method isn't supported as `dart:html` package is missing from the Dart SDK supplied with Flutter and eventually shouldn't be used because of security concerns. (hosting a credentials file inside your built package)

My best suggestion is to create an endpoint for logging at your server-side, where you can use any logging library you wish with any authentication method.